# Create a map to call the POJO for each row of Spark Dataframe

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark, pojo, h2o

I built an H2O model in R and saved the POJO code. I want to score parquet files in hdfs using the POJO but I'm not sure how to go about it. I plan on reading the parquet files into spark (scala/SparkR/PySpark) and scoring them on there. Below is the excerpt I found on [H2O's documentation page.](https://h2o-release.s3.amazonaws.com/h2o/rel-turing/6/docs-website/h2o-docs/pojo-quick-start.html)

> "How do I run a POJO on a Spark Cluster?
>
> The POJO provides just the math logic to do predictions, so you won’t find any  Spark (or even H2O) specific code there. If you want to use the POJO to make  predictions on a dataset in Spark, create a map to call the POJO for each row and save the result to a new column, row-by-row"

Does anyone have some example code of how I can do this? I'd greatly appreciate any assistance. I code primarily in R and SparkR, and I'm not sure how I can "map" the POJO to each line.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just posted a [solution](http://www.highdimensional.space/2017/12/19/scoring-h2o-mojo-models-with-spark-dataframe-and-dataset/) that actually uses DataFrame/Dataset. The post used a Star Wars dataset to build a model in R and then scored MOJO on the test set in Spark. I'll paste the only relevant part here:

#### Scoring with Spark (and Scala)

You could either use spark-submit or spark-shell. If you use spark-submit, h2o-genmodel.jar needs to be put under lib folder of the root directory of your spark application so it could be added as a dependency during compilation. The following code assumes you're running spark-shell. In order to use h2o-genmodel.jar, you need to append the jar file when launching spark-shell by providing a --jar flag. For example:

```
/usr/lib/spark/bin/spark-shell \
--conf spark.serializer="org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer" \
--conf spark.driver.memory="3g" \
--conf spark.executor.memory="10g" \
--conf spark.executor.instances=10 \
--conf spark.executor.cores=4 \
--jars /path/to/h2o-genmodel.jar
```

Now in the Spark shell, import the dependencies

```
import _root_.hex.genmodel.easy.{EasyPredictModelWrapper, RowData}
import _root_.hex.genmodel.MojoModel
```

#### Using DataFrame

```
val modelPath = "/path/to/zip/file"
val dataPath = "/path/to/test/data"

// Import data
val dfStarWars = spark.read.option("header", "true").csv(dataPath)
// Import MOJO model
val mojo = MojoModel.load(modelPath)
val easyModel = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(mojo)

// score
val dfScore = dfStarWars.map {
  x =>
    val r = new RowData
    r.put("height", x.getAs[String](1))
    r.put("mass", x.getAs[String](2))
    val score = easyModel.predictBinomial(r).classProbabilities
    (x.getAs[String](0), score(1))
}.toDF("name", "isHumanScore")
```

The variable score is a list of two scores for level 0 and 1. score(1) is the score for level 1, which is "human". By default the map function returns a DataFrame with unspecified column names "_1", "_2", etc. You can rename the columns by calling toDF.

#### Using Dataset

To use the Dataset API we just need to create two case classes, one for the input data, and one for the output.

```
case class StarWars (
  name: String,
  height: String,
  mass: String,
  is_human: String
)

case class Score (
  name: String,
  isHumanScore: Double
)


// Dataset
val dtStarWars = dfStarWars.as[StarWars]
val dtScore = dtStarWars.map {
  x =>
    val r = new RowData
    r.put("height", x.height)
    r.put("mass", x.mass)
    val score = easyModel.predictBinomial(r).classProbabilities
    Score(x.name, score(1))
}
```

With Dataset you can get the value of a column by calling x.columnName directly. Just notice that the types of the column values have to be String, so you might need to manually cast them if they are of other types defined in the case class.

Comment: This is awesome!! Thank you so much, it is exactly what I was looking for. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to perform scoring with POJO or MOJO in spark you should be using RowData which is provided within h2o-genmodel.jar class as row by row input data to call easyPredict method to generate scores.

Your solution will be to read the parquet file from HDFS and then for each row, convert that to RowData object by filling each entry and then pass that to your POJO scoring function. Remember POJO and MOJO they both use exact same scoring function to score and the only difference is on how the POJO Class is used vs MOJO resources zip package is used. As MOJO are backward compatible and could work with any newer h2o-genmodel.jar it is best if you use MOJO instead of POJO.

Following is the full Scala code you can use on Spark to load a MOJO model and then do the scoring:

```
import _root_.hex.genmodel.GenModel
import _root_.hex.genmodel.easy.{EasyPredictModelWrapper, RowData}
import _root_.hex.genmodel.easy.prediction
import _root_.hex.genmodel.MojoModel
import _root_.hex.genmodel.easy.RowData

// Load Mojo
val mojo = MojoModel.load("/Users/avkashchauhan/learn/customers/mojo_bin/gbm_model.zip")
val easyModel = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(mojo)

// Get Mojo Details
var features = mojo.getNames.toBuffer

// Creating the row
val r = new RowData
r.put("AGE", "68")
r.put("RACE", "2")
r.put("DCAPS", "2")
r.put("VOL", "0")
r.put("GLEASON", "6")

// Performing the Prediction
val prediction = easyModel.predictBinomial(r).classProbabilities
```

[Here](https://dzone.com/articles/reading-nested-parquet-file-in-scala-and-exporting) is an example of reading parquet files in Spark and then saving as CSV. You can use the same code to read the parquet from HDFS and then pass the each row as RowData to above example.

[Here](https://aichamp.wordpress.com/2017/10/20/scoring-h2o-mojo-models-with-spark-udf-and-scala/) is detailed example of using MOJO model in spark and perform scoring using RowData.

Comment: Hi @AvkashChauhan . Thanks so much for your detailed response and providing me with links to examples. This really helps, but I'm still uncertain about one thing however.  Where you mention I can " read the parquet from HDFS and then pass each row as RowData to above example", how exactly do I pass the read in parquet files as Row Data? Say for example I built a model on the Titanic Data Set, and I'd like to score https://raw.githubusercontent.com/agconti/kaggle-titanic/master/data/test.csv , how would I pass the read in data as Row Data and score row by row?

Comment: How would the code you provided above have to change if i were to read in the data linked above? I'm new to scala so apologies if this is a silly question.

Comment: This article shows how you can read parquet file in scala and save to csv. If you dont have nested parquet file, then you just need to use the basic code to read parquet and then save to CSV or feed directly to H2O https://dzone.com/articles/reading-nested-parquet-file-in-scala-and-exporting

Comment: I'm able to read in parquet files with scala, I'm just not sure how to pass each row iteratively into RowData. In the example code you provided above, you create new data. My data set has about 10 million rows, and I'd like to know how to pass each row into the Mojo scoring function. This example, https://github.com/h2oai/h2o-droplets/blob/master/h2o-pojo-on-spark-droplet/src/main/scala/examples/PojoExample.scala, reads in a csv file and scores it using a Pojo. I'd like to read in 10 millions rows (parquet) and score them using mojo. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I will write a sample and share soon.

Comment: Hi @AvkashChauhan. Have you perhaps had the chance to write sample code for our problem? Again, I really appreciate you taking the time to do this. Looking forward to putting our model into production!