# Making predictions using h2o mojo model on spark cluster - parallelisation issues

Tags: scala, apache-spark, h2o

I am having trouble using an h2o model (in mojo format) on a Spark cluster, but only when I try to run it in parallel, not when I use `collect` and run it on the driver.

Since the dataframe I am predicting on has > 100 features, I am using the following function to convert dataframe rows to RowData format for h2o (from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47828510/how-to-map-over-dataframe-in-spark-to-extract-rowdata-and-make-predictions-using)):

```
def rowToRowData(df: DataFrame, row: Row): RowData = {
  val rowAsMap = row.getValuesMap[Any](df.schema.fieldNames)
  val rowData = rowAsMap.foldLeft(new RowData()) { case (rd, (k,v)) =>
    if (v != null) { rd.put(k, v.toString) }
    rd
  }
  rowData
}
```

Then, I import the mojo model and create an easyPredictModel wrapper

```
val mojo = MojoModel.load("/path/to/mojo.zip")
val easyModel = new EasyPredictModelWrapper(mojo)
```

Now, I can make predictions on my dataframe (`df`) by mapping over the rows if I collect it first, so the following works:

```
val predictions = df.collect().map { r =>
  val rData = rowToRowData(df, r) . // convert row to RowData using function
  val prediction = easyModel.predictBinomial(rData).label
  (r.getAs[String]("id"), prediction.toInt)
  }
  .toSeq
  .toDF("id", "prediction")
```

However, I wish to do this in parallel on the cluster since the final df will be too large to collect on the driver. But if I try to run the same code without collecting first:

```
val predictions = df.map { r =>
  val rData = rowToRowData(df, r)
  val prediction = easyModel.predictBinomial(rData).label
  (r.getAs[String]("id"), prediction.toInt)
}
  .toDF("id", "prediction")
```

I get the following errors:

```
18/01/03 11:34:59 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 118.0 (TID 9914, 213.248.241.182, executor 0): java.lang.ClassCastException: cannot assign instance of scala.collection.immutable.List$SerializationProxy to field org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.org$apache$spark$rdd$RDD$$dependencies_ of type scala.collection.Seq in instance of org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$FieldReflector.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:2133)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.setObjFieldValues(ObjectStreamClass.java:1305)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2024)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2018)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1942)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1808)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1353)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:373)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaDeserializationStream.readObject(JavaSerializer.scala:75)
    at org.apache.spark.serializer.JavaSerializerInstance.deserialize(JavaSerializer.scala:114)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:108)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:335)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

So it looks like a datatype mismatch. I have tried converting the dataframe to an rdd first (i.e. `df.rdd.map`, but get the same errors), doing `df.mapPartition`, or placing the `rowToData` function code within the map, but nothing has worked so far.

Any ideas on the best way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

I've found some messy Spark ticket https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18075 describing the same problem related to different ways of submitting Spark application. Take a look, maybe it'll give you a clue about your problem.

Comment: Thanks Dmitry, but when I try to return a row I get compile errors: `Error:(344, 53) Unable to find encoder for type stored in a Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._`          and                `Error:(344, 53) not enough arguments for method map: (implicit evidence$6: org.apache.spark.sql.Encoder[org.apache.spark.sql.Row])org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row].
Unspecified value parameter evidence$6.]`

Comment: Interesting... So the problem is not returning Row, your code should work just fine returning tuple. I've found some messy Spark ticket describing the same problem https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-18075 related to different ways of submitting Spark application. Take a look, maybe it'll give you a clue about your problem.

Comment: Hi @Dmitry - actually, returning a tuple totally works for my purposes, since I can turn that directly into a DataFrame with a `.toDF` call! Thanks for this, if you edit tour original answer then I can accept it as a correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can't call prediction.toInt. The prediction returned is a tuple. You need to extract the second element of that tuple to get the actual score for level 1. I have a complete example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47898040/9120484

Comment: Thanks for the link. I did see your answer - but I needed something that did not involve pre-specifying the row names and types. And in this case you can call `prediction.toInt` since the prediction result in not a probability tuple, it is the label, or result of `.predictBinomial(rData).label`).